# Salary Raise after 6 months

Tags: salary, negotiation, contracts, salaried-pay, payscale

During the interview process when negotiating my salary and ontract my employer advised that my salary could be increased after 6 months depending on performance. Should I go about asking whether this was still the case?

If so how should I go about this? I do feel I offer a lot to the team and have taken on a lot of "above my Head" projects since I have started here and feel I have exceled in these given my experience.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Have you been there for 6 months without anybody in management raising this?  If so, then I don't think it unreasonable for you to broach this politely with your manager.  If it's not yet been 6 months, then wait.

Comment: Asked plenty of times before, see [this search](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=promised+raise+is%3Aq) for instance.

Comment: Keyword is *could* which could mean maybe, or maybe not. Just ask about it and see where they stand.

Answer (score 3):

When you start a new job it is not unnusual to be promised a raise at a later date depending on performance. This is the traditional carrot and stick scenario.

#### The Stick:

You're new at your job, probably on probation, and know you can be let go on a moment's notice.

#### The Carrot:

Management tells you to work hard and you'll get a reward!

#### The Reality:

The sad truth is that more often than not the promise of a raise is just a platitude in order to inspire you to put in your best effort. If your 6 months are nearly over you may want to ask your manager whether you could sit down with him and ask for his opinion on your performance, and any advice he might have for you.

If he brings up a raise, then great. If he doesn't, that should tell you all you need to know.

Keep in mind that companies don't simply hand out raises willy nilly. If you're hired to do X, for $Y, and a year later you're still only doing X, then what is their motivation for paying you more? You're not bringing more value to the company.

However, if you do X really, *really* well, propose an improvement to the process, and have double the productivity of anyone else doing that same job, then you have a basis on which to ask for more money.

Keep all this in mind when you go speak to your manager. Raises are never implied, they're earned, and you have to prove that you've earned yours.

Comment: I really like this answer, however, a raise not asked for is a raise not received (usually). I would absolutely set up the meeting and give your boss the opportunity to raise the issue first, however, if the boss doesn't raise it, you should.

Comment: I read a article once that the top reason nobody gets a raise is mostly due to simply not asking. If you ask, "Where is my raise I was promised?" then you might get a actual raise.

Comment: Yep, I'd just cut through the tape and ask "When am I getting my raise boss?"